# Easy editable table in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to programming and learning as I build more... I am working on creating a view to show a data table on the html page and used the below code so far..

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class MySetters(models.Model):
    mytsettername = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Allowed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
def __str__(Self):
    return self.mytablename
```

**views.py**

```
def setterveiew(request):
    context = {'setterlist':MySetters.objects.all}
    return render(request,'setterspage.html',context)
```

I was able to add it to the template and display the table and data.

However, this table is currently readyonly.. is there a way to make it editable in line. read a lot of articles online however all of them are using ajax and jquery and I have no clue in that language and how to implement that.

Also, Can someone please advise how to add a check box to the table so that users can select multiple of them and hit a button so that an action can be performed.

Please advise.

Thank you